# How to test a javascript infinite recursive worker function scenario

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to test the following "worker" method in a Class without success as it is "an infinite loop"/recursive:

```
Class TheClassYaDaYaDa {
    constructor(var1) {
        (...)
    }

    async worker() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                await this.doStuff();
                return resolve();
            } catch (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } finally {
                this.worker();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is the test I'm building:

```
it('It should not throw error', async function () {
    let error = false;
    const var1 = 'parameterTest';
    stub1 = sinon.stub(TheClassYaDaYaDa.prototype, 'doStuff').resolves();

    // if I use the following stub logically the test will not succeed. If I don't I get an infinte loop
    // stub2 = sinon.stub(TheClassYaDaYaDa.prototype, 'worker').resolves();

    let classToTest;
    try {
        classToTest = new TheClassYaDaYaDa(limitedInstance);
        result = await classToTest.worker();
    } catch (err) {
        error = err;
    }
    expect(error).to.be.false;
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stub1);
    
    //also assert that the finally statement run at least once!
});
```

Is there a way to test this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this from a different angle, recursion is always tricky but one of the popular designs is to split the scheduling and running logic into two.

Consider the following:

```
async worker() {
    await this.scheduleWorker();
}

private scheduleWorker() {
    // return new Promise ...
}
```

It's now possible to test that the scheduleWorker function calls worker, and also that worker calls scheduleWorker (if private methods are accessible).

If not, you could mock the worker method to only return the worker logic on the first call and noops on subsequent calls. This would also work for your current design allowing you to assert the recursive call was correctly triggered.

I am not well versed on sinon but you want something similar to:

```
var originalWorker = classToTest.originalWorker;
classToTest.originalWorker = function() {
    originalWorker();
    classToTest.originalWorker = function() { }
}
```

Most mocking frameworks have similar controls to enable mocking methods multiple times (for subsequent calls).